# QuickBooks: unresolved SDK reference?

Tags: c#, interop, reference, quickbooks

When I build the MCInvoiceAddQBFC C# application of the sample QuickBooks SDK code, the build fails with

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Interop.QBFC8, Version=8.0.0.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31d8aec643e18259". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. 

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /platform:x86 /errorreport:Prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Vsa.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Deployment.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Design.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Security.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\MCInvoiceAddQBFC.exe /resource:obj\Debug\MCInvoiceAddQBFC.Form1.resources /resource:obj\Debug\IntuitQBFC.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs SessionFramework\Defaults.cs SessionFramework\ENEdition.cs SessionFramework\Logger.cs SessionFramework\QBException.cs SessionFramework\QBNoResponseException.cs SessionFramework\QBResultException.cs SessionFramework\SessionManager.cs 

C:\Users\ESSEFF\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\MCInvoiceAddQBFC\Intuit_QBFC\Form1.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Interop' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

C:\Users\ESSEFF\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\MCInvoiceAddQBFC\Intuit_QBFC\SessionFramework\SessionManager.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Interop' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Looking at the Solution Explorer I see there's a warning sign about Interop.QBFC8, which agrees with the first warning line in the build output. I did install the SDK, and I also tried removing and adding the reference again. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently are not referencing the DLL correctly. I am not familiar with the QuickBooks SDK, but if you notice your *csc.exe* line, there is no reference to any QuickBooks dll.

Have you added the proper reference in each project in your solution?

**Edit:** Is the Interop.QBFC assembly listed under the *.NET* tab when you choose *Add reference...* from the project menu? Check that the file exists there. Alternately, add a reference to the DLL explicitly by browsing to the path that the file exists. You can even copy the DLL to your project folder first.

**Edit:** Referencing a COM interface creates the Interop.XXX.dll dynamically. If QBFC8 is added as a COM reference, make sure you see it in the References folder. You may need to change `using Interop.QBFC8;` to `using QBFC8;`. The first thing I noticed, as I mentioned was that your *csc.exe* line does not show the proper reference. Here is the line when I build a project with a different COM reference:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll"
    /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" 
    /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll 
    /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Deployment.dll 
    /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll 
    /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll 
    /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll 
    /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll 
    /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 

    /reference:obj\Debug\Interop.COMSVCSLib.dll

    /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- 
    /out:obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe 
    /resource:obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.resources 
    /resource:obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe
    Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs
```

If you are not seeing the `/reference:obj\Debug\Interop.XXX.dll`, you need to look at your references again.

Comment: If deployment is a concern, and you are receiving an error on the client, someone else may have had a similar issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/50ca7296-4a59-4c2c-8c8e-abe40ff4ba21/

Comment: Do you mean Project->Add Reference ? In fact, I'm talking about the SDK sample code, so I expect merely opening the project and building it would just work. I did try creating a new project, adding the COM reference from the SDK, and then writing a single `using Interop.QBFC8;`. This resulted in a similar error of the reference not resolved.

Comment: Deployment is not an issue -- yet. I'm working locally on my own machine, and I can't even get the sample code to build.

Comment: The .NET tab doesn't list the reference. It's a COM object, and the SDK references are listed in the COM tab.

Comment: your using statement likely should just be QBFC8, not Interop.QBFC8

Comment: Oh my! I think I see the issue now. Indeed, there's a bad dll reference: the dll is in ...\Program Files (x86)\... Where on Earth this bizarre folder name came from is beyond me. This laptop isn't mine. :-S I think this implies there's a bug in the SDK installer or in the SDK samples, because the installer installs the files in one place while the samples' references refer to another.

Comment: Oh would that we could build every samples distribution with no modifications. Alas, sometimes we need to change one thing or another, hopefully as simple as a directory reference.
Check the errors, and see if you can manually update references.
I suggest the change in `using` statement, because when I add a reference to a COM object from within VS, it creates a namespace of "XYZ", but a dll named "Interop.XYZ.dll". Confusing? Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a reference to

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\Interop.QBFC8.dll
```